# PermissionError While Installing TensorFlow Using Virtualenv

Tags: tensorflow, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

I was installing tensorflow using virtualenv. The following commands worked fine.

```
$ virtualenv ~/.tensorflow/bin/activate
$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

But if I try:

```
$ virtualenv ~/.tensorflow/bin/activate
$ pip3 install tensorflow
```

I got PermissionError:

[image]

I tried the last command with sudo.

```
$ sudo pip3 install tensorflow
```

Then it seems like I can import tensorflow outside virtualenv.
(Is it correct?)

How can I install tensorflow for python 3 only inside virtualenv?

By the way, I am using pip 9.0.1 for both python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2.

The version of virtualenv is 15.0.1.

Comment: I think `pip3` is pointing to python3 installed in `/home/gyuhyeon/.local` where as `pip` is pointing to `~/.tensorflow/bin/pip`. you can check this using `which pip3`

Comment: @AshokaLella I got this: /home/gyuhyeon/.local/bin/pip3. Is something wrong?

Comment: @AshokaLella It seems wrong... How can I solve this?

Comment: If your virtual environment is in python3. Running `pip install tesnsorflow` should install it in your python3 environment.

Comment: @AshokaLella I cannot import tensorflow in ipython3. And there is no pip3 under ~/.tensorflow/bin/...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Does Happen If I Use Sudo Pip in Python Virtualenv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037983/what-does-happen-if-i-use-sudo-pip-in-python-virtualenv)

Comment: @alvits Yes, I asked one more question while I was finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

For python2:

```
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/.tensorflow
$ source ~/.tensorflow/bin/activate
(.tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

For python3:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.5 --system-site-packages ~/.tensorflow3
$ source ~/.tensorflow3/bin/activate
(.tensorflow3)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Using these ways, I could successfully install tensorflow only inside virtualenvs.

Thank you so much @AshokaLella!

Comment: `source ~/.tensorflow3/bin/activate`  worked.  Leaving off the file extension worked.  My output is:
`(tensorflow) stephen@machine:~/Projects/pluralsight/tensorflow$`

Answer (score 1):

If your virtual environment is in python3. Running pip install tensorflow should install it in your python3 environment.

```
$ virtualenv3 venv 
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install tensorflow
(venv)$ pip freeze
appdirs==1.4.3
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
protobuf==3.3.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
(venv) $>python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 16 2017, 12:12:55) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20170109] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>>
```

If you are running

```
virtualenv ~/.tensorflow/bin/activate
```

make sure virtualenv is for python3. And your virtual env will get created at `~/.tensorflow/bin/activate` (Not sure if you want that). I'd suggest change that address to something simple, and make sure it does not contain the folder named as some of the libraries you want to import. It causes problems sometimes.

If you're trying to import tf in ipython3, you should also make sure that ipython is installed in the same environment. And if you run

```
ipython notebook
```

This will launch the default ipython (/usr/bin/ipython). You dont want that. So, run `venv/bin/ipython3` instead

Comment: I do not have virtualevn3...? Even though it says "python3-virtualenv is already the newest version (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1)."

Comment: python3-virtualenv is same as virtualenv3. I'm using a different OS

Comment: I could solve the problem because of your advices! Is it find if I answer the solution I found?

Comment: yeah, no problem