# What Does Happen If I Use Sudo Pip in Python Virtualenv?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

What does happen if I install something using pip/pip3 with sudo privilege in virtualevn?

I got PermissionError while installing tensorflow with pip3 inside virtualenv, so I used sudo.

```
(.tensorflow) $ pip3.5 install tensorflow
...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages'
(.tensorflow) $ sudo pip3.5 install tensorflow
```

Then I can import tensorflow in ipython3 outside virtualenv.

However, I did not get PermissionError when I installed using pip2.

So, if I install something inside virtualenv with sudo privilege, is it accessible from outside?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your virtualenv using Python 3.5 as its interpreter? You can check this by just running `python --version` with the virtualenv activated. Based on your statements I suspect you have a 2.7 virtualenv. Since the virtualenv is 2.7 `pip3.5` is not operating within the context of the virtual environment, which is why you needed to use `sudo`. `virtualenv -p python3.5 myvenvname` should give you what you want.

Comment: Yes, 2.7.12 and 3.5.2. I think pip3 points ~/.local/pip3... Do you know how to solve this?