# cannot activate virtualenv environment -- tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I'm trying to install tensorflow. I downloaded tensorflow successfully using pip3. But when I try to activate environment by:

```html
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
```

my prompt doesn't change.

When I tried:

```html
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh
```

it says:

```html
-bash: alias: deactivate: not found
-bash: alias: `test $?_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH !': invalid alias name
-bash: setenv: command not found
-bash: setenv: command not found
-bash: /Users/bingyaoli/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh: line 37: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/44038109/3148952

Comment: Activating virtualenv doesn't always result in changing the prompt. Prompt is changed only if the activation script contains necessary commands to change the prompt. The fact that prompt hasn't changed doesn't indicate that the virtualenv wasn't activated.

Answer (score 8):

Tried:

```
source ~/tensor_flow/bin/activate
```

[sans the .csh extension] and it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18663016)

Comment: This actually did provide an answer to me, @GillesGouaillardet - though I was using a different directory structure, the advice and the explanation worked for me.  I think what may be happening here is that the same error message may be indicative of two different problems... perhaps it's a version issue?  Cheers!

Comment: @Maashu The initial "question" stated this command did not work. I am glad this command inspired you and solved your problem, but back to this thread, it did not answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh
```

try:

```
csh ~/tensorflow/bin/activate.csh
```

this fixes the problem.

Comment: This is a good solution. csh is actually not a bash script - it is the c shell virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not as the sudo user at the terminal.

Try giving "su username"

then it will ask password; give that and then give

"source ~/tensorflow/venv/bin/activate" (based on whatever path you have),

it will work!